# Laravel 4 favourite comment pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to add functionality to a site for a user to favourite a comment.

Adding/displaying comments works fine. I'm just struggling to get my head around this.

**User Model:**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
    protected $fillable = array('username', 'password', 'email');



    //Attach comment to user
    public function addComment($id)
    {

        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $this->comments()->attach($id);

            return true;
        }

        throw new UnexpectedValueException;
    }

    //Retrieve user comments
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Comment');
    }

    //Attach favourite comment to user
    public function addFavouriteComment($id)
    {

        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $this->favouriteComment()->attach($id);

            return true;
        }

        throw new UnexpectedValueException;
    }

    //Retrieve user favourite comments
    public function favouriteComments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('FavouriteComment');
    }

}
```

**User Table:**

```
table name = user: 
username             
password         
email        
remember_token
created_at
updated_at
```

**Comment Model:**

```
<?php

    class Comment extends Eloquent
    {
        protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'content');

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'comment_user');
        }
    }
```

**Comment table:**

```
table name = comments: 
id
content
created_at
updated_At

table name = comment_user: 
user_id
comment_id
```

**Favourite Model:**

```
<?php

    class FavouriteComment extends Eloquent
    {
        protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'comment_id');

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'comment_user');
        }
    }
```

Favourite Comment table:

```
table name = favourite_comment_user: 
user_id
favourite_comment_id
```

Attaching a favourite comment to a user works fine.

```
$user = Auth::user();

$user->addFavouriteComment($id);
```

But when I try and get attached favourite comments from a user

```
$user->favouriteComments()->get()
```

I get this error:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pcc_archive.favourite_comments' doesn't exist
```

Comment: You don't have favourite_comments table, do you? use `protected $table` on the `FavouriteComment` model then

Comment: @deczo I don't have a table called favourite_comments, what would I set $table to?

Comment: To your table name obviously :) Suppose it refers to `comments` just like `Comment` model, correct?